# Support of a Set in sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $I$ be a large index set (you can think I being the set of reals), and
for each $i \in I$  we have a $\sigma$-algebra $\Omega_i$ on the set $X_i$.

Consider the Cartesian product $X =\prod_{i\in I} X_i$, and the $\sigma$-algebra on X generated by the sets $A =\prod_{i\in I} A_i$, where $A_i\in \Omega_i$, and all $A_i$, with a single exception,
is equal to $X_i$. The support of a subset $A \subseteq X$ is the largest subset $J$ of the indices such that for every $a \in A$, changing $a$ at an index not in $J$, the new element is still in $A$.
Show that every element of $\Omega$ has a countable support.

Any Hints on how to start?

Comment: I would do this by a transfinite induction up to $\omega_1$. Have you learned about that?

Comment: thank you Brian. Unfortunately we didn't. I will read and try to figure it out @BrianO

Comment: I bet the Monotone class theorem "packages up" a transfinite induction up to $\omega_1$, hiding the details. The basic idea: a $\sigma$-algebra is constructed in $\omega_1$ stages. Stage $0$ = the sets that generate the $\sigma$-algebra; at stage $\alpha+1$, form countable unions of sets in stage $\alpha$, and complements of sets in stage $\alpha$; stage $\lambda$ for limit ordinals $\lambda$ = union of stages $\alpha < \lambda$. As it happens, at stage $\omega_1$ you're done, it's a $\sigma$-algebra. The support of every element is a countable union of countable sets, so it's countable.

Comment: i will use that, thank you @BrianO

Comment: Glad it helps, you're welcome. Re my last remark: since every element of the $\sigma$-algebra occurs at a countable stage, the proposition "the support of every element is countable" follows by *transfinite induction* up to/below  $\omega_1$. At stages $0$ and limits $\lambda$ there's nothing to prove. At a successor stage $\alpha +1$, assuming it's true for everything in stage $\alpha$, you have to show it for complements and countable unions. That's where you use "the countable union of countable sets is countable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Monotone class theorem.  (More specifically, the $\pi$–$\lambda$ form.) Your system of generators is a $\pi$-system, and the class of sets with the desired property is a $\lambda$-system.